# Portable radio for cockpit communication

Tags: radio-communications, radio

I am a private pilot based at Van Nuys airport in Los Angeles. Recently due to traffic congestion we have to hold short for extended periods of time, 20-25 minutes.

I thought to get a portable radio to be able to turn the airplane engine and master switches off and save on the rental fee and the constant breaking.

Any recommendations about the specifications of a say 5-10 nautical mile range portable radio is appreciated.

Comment: You won't significantly run a battery down with everything off but a comm radio turned on and listening in. GA comm radios are generally around 5 watts transmitting, much less when in receive mode, a couple watts at most.  You're talking a fraction of an amp current draw.  A 12 vdc 25 Amp Hr battery will take a day or two to run down. And you're starting a warm engine.  If a battery can't start a warm engine after running a radio in receive mode for 30 min with 5 seconds transmitting, that's a battery that's done, and whether you had the radio on or not will have made little difference.

Comment: Not to say you shouldn't buy a backup radio if you fly from a place like Van Nuys; you should have one anyway if you fly in any kind of busy airspace.

Comment: @John K. they charge the hubs time. not the tachometer.

Comment: Hobbs is activated by oil pressure.  It only records while the engine is running.  Next time you shut down, leave the master on and observe the meter for 6 minutes and you'll see it stopped counting.

Comment: @JohnK Note that some greedy FBOs rewire the Hobbs to the master for such reasons.

Comment: Yikes!  If I caught someone renting a plane to me doing that, they'd get an earful from me and I certainly wouldn't rent from them knowing I'm paying 2 dollars a minute for the use of the battery.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a portable, handheld transceiver. It can very well come in handy in an emergency. Especially one with GPS, VOR, and ILS. Make sure you get a headset adapter with it.

Do not use it to save money during a long hold-short request. Turning the engine off after you have done your run up is not recommended. It is defeating the purpose of the run up. A better technique is to get your flight following discrete squawk code and/or clearance delivery electronically, by phone, or by handheld before turning on the Master and engine.